# Instagram API - Can't get media of a private user who has accepted follow request

Tags: php, objective-c, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the Instagram API in an app to see photos of other Instagrammers.

If an Instagram account is private those photos cannot be seen and this makes sense. However, if that private Instagram has accepted the follow request of the user (access token) requesting their media, then that media
should be available (right?) but I am still receiving an error when making the request.

I am using this request endpoint:

```
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/PRIVATE_PROFILE_ID/media/recent/
    ?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_USER_THAT_IS_ALLOWED_TO_FOLLOW_PRIVATE_PROFILE
```

**Is it simply the case that the API doesn't grant access to private profiles regardless of whether the requesting access token has permission
to follow that profile or not?**

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371309/instagram-api-cant-find-info-on-private-profiles) but not really answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 1st 2016, the API no longer allows access to private profiles even if the API request is made using a `access_token` of user that is approved to access the private profile.

Comment: Happy to accept answer but do you have a reference ?

Comment: no reference, try API for private user it does not work, I have an email from Instagram developer confirming this.

Comment: Ya I'm aware it doesn't work but was just wondering if it's an API bug or officially documented somewhere. Does the email from the Instagram developer confirm that it is intentional or simply recognise that it doesn't currently work?

Comment: it is intentional, they did it cause 3rd party apps were displaying private profiles on websites and it was getting SEO'ed and appearing in google search, and users were complaining, so Instagram decided to remove access to private profile via API

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. Thanks